# as a Service connecting remote WMI query errors out with wrong user

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, remote-access

Ok, first of all here is the error message from WMI-Activity / Operational in EventLog (Windows 8):

Id = ; ClientMachine = machinename; User = machinename\Dev; ClientProcessId = 1440; Component = WMIService; Operation = connect to namespace : root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption; ResultCode = 0x80041003; PossibleCause = the user was not granted appropriate permission on the namespace.

the thing is  User name "Dev" is not the username that I fed to the ConnectionOptions of ManagementScope() when I attempted connection to remote computer.

The machinename(I hide) was correct.

Trying to make a remote connection is a service and most suspicious scenario is service running as local machine somehow overwrites the username..

I need a confirmation with somebody who might know and able to explain what I am doing wrong here..

I see Username and Password are correct until fed into properties of ConnectionOptions and made Scope.Connect() call.

Comment: it is remote for sure because you dont use different machine name for local..

Comment: Is this a Domain or workgroup environment? If its domain, is the account that's being giving to Connection Options the same account that is being used for all WMI calls or specific to that machine. If the same account is being used for all you might just trying running the service as that account and leaving the options out of your scope call and see if it acts better.